# PHP - parse space limited text file

Tags: php, parsing

I know there's similar info on here, but I'm being really dense today and can't seem to follow them and piece them into what I need. I'm also very new with PHP.

I have a text file hosted on another server (actually a Dropbox server) that contains space-delimited text, like so:

McDonalds Odana Rd
Petsmart Verona Rd
Like a Kite Knickerbocker Ave

And I want to input it, parse it, and regurgitate it as google search links, like so:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/search?q=McDonalds+Odana+Rd">McDonalds Odana Rd</a>
```

If I was sure I was the only person editing the text file, I could come up with easier delimiters, but this is part of an application that needs to be exceedingly easy to use. I could probably get away with enforcing an end-of-line character if needed.

Thank you so much for helping me through my brain fog.

Comment: `$str=str_replace(' ','+',$text); ` might do the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple. Take the text, use [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) on it, and then hard-`echo` it into the link. Something like this:

```
$file = fopen('text.txt', 'r') or die('error');
while ($text = fgets($file)) {
    $encode = urlencode($text);
    echo "<a href='http://www.google.com/search?q=$encode'>$text</a>";
}
```

Comment: That looks like a perfect solution. I'm embarrassed to say that I didn't turn on email responses and forgot all about this, and now I don't even remember what project it was for.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
<?php    
$fields=explode(" ",file_get_contents(<filepath>));
foreach ($fields as $place)
echo '<a href="http://www.google.com/search?q='.$place.'">'.$place.'</a>';
?>
```